# Rewrite this IN query using JOIN for speedy results

Tags: mysql, join

I have this query which works but it takes 30 mintues to calculate.  I know IN is slow, but looking for a join alternative.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as Results from member_preferences_products_data
        WHERE member_preferences_products_data.Member_ID IN (SELECT Member_ID from member_preferences_products_data WHERE Product_ID = '623')
        GROUP by Product_ID
        ORDER by Results asc
        LIMIT 10
```

Comment: And I'm sure you've done some reasearch or googling that you are now going to edit your question and add it in ... surely your not just asking us to do your work for you ?

Comment: I have tried, but it generates the wrong results. I've got a number of joins on other queries which all work, so I'm not sure why mine doesn't.

Comment: Come on. Let's see that JOIN

Comment: So you have made several attempts and have decided not to show us these ? your question should have been: "I am trying to find an IN alternative, Here is my original query, I tried X, Y, Z but it gives me results like 1, when I need results like 2. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong." This shows a level of effort for one and gives someone something to work off, rather than say heres my code, fix it!

Comment: I apologise.  I was working on something else and I admit I didn't really spend time on my post.  Won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

A direct replacement for you query would be

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as Results 
FROM member_preferences_products_data
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Member_ID
    FROM member_preferences_products_data 
    WHERE Product_ID = '623'
) Sub1
ON member_preferences_products_data.Member_ID = Sub1.Member_ID
GROUP by Product_ID
ORDER by Results asc
LIMIT 10
```

However I am a bit confused about what you are trying to find. It seems you want a count of the rows for each product id where that product id has been bought by a member who bought product id 623.

Also, if the field Product_ID a string or an INT. If an INT the quotes are not required, but if it is a string then it will probably be slower than an INT field assuming the values are numeric

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you.  That's exactly what I was looking for on the results.